# changing state with Array.map doesn't update state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-state

I am mapping through an array like this

```
const isFocused = useIsFocused();

async function getProfile() {
const [labels, setLabels] = useState([])
...

array.map(x => {
            handleChange(x.date)
          })
...
    }

useEffect(() => {
    isFocused && getProfile()
  }, [isFocused]);
```

The code for handleChange()

```
function handleChange(date) {
    console.log(date,"THIS IS DATE IN HANDLE")
    setLabels([...labels, date])
  }
```

The value of label after this is only the last index of the array. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: on what action you want to set it or is it on initial render's ?

Comment: @KcH added more details to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mutate state directly. You need to make a copy of the state and then mutate the copy.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use an temporary array to store the gathered result first then set the state.

Since setState in React is asynchronous, the program may get the state which is not updated (Always empty) until the last setState.

```
const [labels, setLabels] = useState([])

let temp = [...labels];   //Get Any pre-stored items
array.map(x => {
  console.log(date,"THIS IS DATE IN HANDLE")
  temp.push(labels);
})

setLabels(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are trying to do,If `getProfile`is a component (make it Pascal case), you may want it to do in an *useEffect* as

```
const [labels, setLabels] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const changedLabels = array.map((x) => {
    return handleChange(x.date);
  });

  function handleChange(date) {
    // do w/e intended to be ... 
    return handledData;
  }

  setLabels([...labels, ...changedLabels]);
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had `the available data` as `MOCKUP_DATA` or this data have gotten from `Props of component`, and you need `setState` at first time. You can do like this:

```
const MOCKUP_DATA = [{date: '123'}, {date: '456'}] 

export default function App() {
const [labels, setLabels] = useState(() => {
  let values = [];
  for(let item of MOCKUP_DATA) {
    values.push(item.date)
  }
  return values
})

  return (
    <ul className="App">
      {labels.map((item, index) => <li key={index}>{item}</li>)}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

But if `value not avaiable` is like as `get value after call api`. You can do like this:

```
  const [labels, setLabels] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // ... Call API
    let newValues = [];
    for (let item of response?.array) {
      newValues.push(item.date);
    }

    setLabels([...labels, ...newValues]);
  }, []);
```